# How to stop a MassTransit bus in an ASP.NET Core server?

Tags: c#, masstransit, kestrel-http-server, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am studying MassTransit and ASP.NET Core, dependancy injection and successfully implemented something that works. I plan to use the Kestrel web server.

So I had to configure my ASP.NET core project this way in the `Startup.cs`.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    ...

    var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(sbc => {
        var host = sbc.Host(new Uri(address), h => {
            h.Username("guest");
            h.Password("guest");
        });
    });

    services.AddSingleton<IBus>(bus);
    services.AddScoped<IRequestClient<GetTagRequest, GetTagAnswer>>(x =>
        new MessageRequestClient<GetTagRequest, GetTagAnswer>(x.GetRequiredService<IBus>(), new Uri(address + "/gettagrequest"), timeOut));

    bus.Start(); // <= ok. how is the bus supposed to stop ?

    ...
```

Although this works fine, no tutorial mentioned anything about setting `bus.Stop()` in an ASP.NET core project. I read in MassTransit documentation that a running bus could prevent a graceful exit.

- Is this a major concern for a Kestrel web server? I have read about process recycling and I am afraid a running bus would compromise this.
- At which place can I place that `bus.Stop()` in an ASP.NET Core project ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `ApplicationLifetime` events. Just make your `IBus` object class level variable.

```
public class Startup
{
    private IBus _bus;

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        /* ... */

        _bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq ... 

        /* ... */
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
    {
        appLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() => _bus.Start());
        appLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() => _bus.Stop());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is `IApplicationLifetime` in .NET Core, which has several `CancellationToken` properties, including `ApplicationStopped`. So when you need to do something after asp.net application is shutdown and all requests are processed (like stopping your bus) - you can do it like this:

```
// lifetime will be injected to Configure from DI container
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IApplicationLifetime lifetime) {
    // subscribe to ApplicationStopped
    lifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(OnApplicationStopped);
    // the rest
}

private void OnApplicationStopped() {
    _bus.Stop();
}
```

It's always good to explicitly release resources even on process shutdown. For example, some message might still be in transition when the process will be killed after shutdown. Doing explicit dispose will allow this transition to complete.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the existing answers:

1. If you use the `MassTransit.AspNetCore`'s `IServiceCollection.AddMassTransit()` extension method, there's no need for a class level `IBus` instance. `Startup`'s `Configure()` supports DI, so you can do this instead:

   ```cs
   public void Configure(IApplicationLifetime appLifetime, IBus bus)
   {
       appLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() => bus.Start());
       appLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() => bus.Stop());
   }
   ```

   If you don't want to use the package, you can still register IBus with the DI container (like in the question) and request it from `Configure()`.
2. The [ASP.NET Core DI sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-DotNetCore-Request) uses an IHostedService instead:

   ```cs
   public class BusService : IHostedService
   {
       private readonly IBusControl _busControl;
       public BusService(IBusControl busControl)
       {
           _busControl = busControl;
       }

       public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
           _busControl.StartAsync(cancellationToken);

       public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
           _busControl.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
   }
   ```

   The service is registered as:

   ```cs
   services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, BusService>();
   ```

   For more information on `IHostedService`, here's the [doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice). I'm not sure I like the idea of having a background service just to stop the bus. Anyway, the sample repo I picked this example from is worth referring to.
3. The third option is to do it yourself in `Main()`. Something like:

   ```cs
   var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
   var bus = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>();

   await bus.StartAsync();
   await host.RunAsync();
   await bus.StopAsync();
   ```